# Access parent constructor in Ember.js object

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember.js, how do I access the parent objects constructor? I did find this while poking around:

```
this.__ember_meta__.proto.__proto__.__proto__.constructor
```

Which yields the correct value, but that's unacceptable for reasons which should be obvious.

Looking at the code in the `extend()` method, it looks like it's assigning the parent class to a property named `superclass`, but I'm not seeing that in my classes for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [definition of the `extend` method](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/core_object.js#L555), you can see it building up and returning a variable called `Class`. You should picture your methods as running on an *instance* of that `Class` (meaning that `this.prototype === Class.prototype`).

With that in mind, you can see that this `Class` itself is being assigned to `Class.prototype.constructor`:

```
proto = Class.prototype = o_create(this.prototype); 
proto.constructor = Class;
```

So you can access this `Class` using `this.constructor`, and furthermore, the constructor of the parent class is being (as you noted) assigned to the `.superclass` property of `Class`:

```
Class.superclass = this;
```

So I believe that the answer you seek is simply:

```
this.constructor.superclass
```

Observe: http://jsfiddle.net/99gvpqzx/1/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle... I wouldn't have believed you otherwise. It looks like the behavior changed somewhere between Ember 1.7.1 (which is what I'm running) and the latest version. Ember 1.7.1 insists that `this.constructor.superclass` is the same as `this.constructor`!

http://jsfiddle.net/99gvpqzx/2/

Comment: @LukeTheObscure Looks like that's not quite right. In your version, it looks like the original class can be accessed with `this.constructor.superclass.superclass` (two `.superclass`es). I guess the `extend()` operation in older versions introduced one more layer of inheritance compared to the newer versions: http://jsfiddle.net/99gvpqzx/2/